# Multiple Grouping in Mongo Aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

My mongo db data is like

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af2"), "email" : "abc@gmail.com", "phone" : 1234 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af3"), "email" : "efg@gmail.com", "phone" : 2346 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af4"), "email" : "abc@gmail.com", "phone" : 7896 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af5"), "phone" : 5789, "email" : "abc@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af6"), "phone" : 7896, "email" : "hij@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af7"), "phone" : 3492, "email" : "lmn@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af8"), "phone" : 5555, "email" : "cdf@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e87ea96774f88e108b4567"), "phone" : 5789, "email" : "abc@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e880db6774f8130f8b4567"), "phone" : 5789, "email" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e880e56774f81f108b4567"), "phone" : 1234, "email" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e880f96774f83b108b4567"), "phone" : 9846, "email" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e881016774f83b108b4568"), "phone" : 1012, "email" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e8812a6774f8c0108b4567"), "phone" : 1258 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e881496774f80e108b4567"), "phone" : 1012, "email" : "" }
```

I want to group first based on the email anf then by using phone.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af2"), "email" : "abc@gmail.com", "phone" : 1234 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af3"), "email" : "efg@gmail.com", "phone" : 2346 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af6"), "phone" : 7896, "email" : "hij@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af7"), "phone" : 3492, "email" : "lmn@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af8"), "phone" : 5555, "email" : "cdf@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e880f96774f83b108b4567"), "phone" : 9846, "email" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e881016774f83b108b4568"), "phone" : 1012, "email" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e8812a6774f8c0108b4567"), "phone" : 1258 }
```

I want all the email ids except the null values with correcsponding phone numbers. Also want Phone numbers which doesn't have the same email ids as of the group email. Phone numbers with null email id or without key email also should be included in the output.

Thanking you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) aggregate command, to group by email and then phone you must use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) with a final [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to clean up.

## First solution without duplicate suppression

```
db.data.aggregate([       {$group: {_id: {$cond: {if: {"$eq": ['$email', '']}, else: {email: '$email'}, then: {phone: '$phone', email: '$email'}}}, firstId: {$first: '$_id'}, phone: {$first: '$phone'}}},        {$project: {_id: '$firstId', phone: '$phone', email: '$_id.email'}}     ])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e880f96774f83b108b4567"), "phone" : 9846, "email" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e881016774f83b108b4568"), "phone" : 1012, "email" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e880e56774f81f108b4567"), "phone" : 1234, "email" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e880db6774f8130f8b4567"), "phone" : 5789, "email" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af8"), "phone" : 5555, "email" : "cdf@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af6"), "phone" : 7896, "email" : "hij@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af7"), "phone" : 3492, "email" : "lmn@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af3"), "phone" : 2346, "email" : "efg@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e8812a6774f8c0108b4567"), "phone" : 1258 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af2"), "phone" : 1234, "email" : "abc@gmail.com" }
```

### Second solution with duplicate suppression

```
db.data.aggregate([
  {$group: {_id: '$phone', emails: {$addToSet: {email: '$email', _id: '$_id'}}, countNonBlank: {$sum: {$cond: [{$eq: ['$email', '']}, 0,  1]}}}}, {$unwind: {path: '$emails', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}}, 
  {$match: {$or: [{'emails.email': {$ne: ''}}, {"countNonBlank": {$lt: 1}, "emails.email": {$eq: ''}}]}}, 
  {$project: {phone: '$_id', email: '$emails.email', _id: '$emails._id'}}, 
  {$group: {_id: {email: '$email', phone: '$phone'}, firstId: {$first: '$_id'}}}, 
  {$project: {_id: '$firstId', phone: '$_id.phone', email: '$_id.email'}}, 
  {$group: {_id: {$cond: {if: {"$eq": ['$email', '']}, else: {email: '$email'}, then: {phone: '$phone', email: '$email'}}}, firstId: {$first: '$_id'}, phone: {$first: '$phone'}}},        
  {$project: {_id: '$firstId', phone: '$phone', email: '$_id.email'}}     
])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e881496774f80e108b4567"), "phone" : 1012, "email" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e880f96774f83b108b4567"), "phone" : 9846, "email" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af3"), "phone" : 2346, "email" : "efg@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af7"), "phone" : 3492, "email" : "lmn@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af6"), "phone" : 7896, "email" : "hij@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af8"), "phone" : 5555, "email" : "cdf@gmail.com" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e8812a6774f8c0108b4567"), "phone" : 1258 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af2"), "phone" : 1234, "email" : "abc@gmail.com" }
```

Comment: This seems working. But I want { "_id" : ObjectId("58e880f96774f83b108b4567"), "phone" : 9846, "email" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58e881016774f83b108b4568"), "phone" : 1012, "email" : "" } record too in my output.

Comment: Hi Julien TASSIN, 
Can you please have a look in the question again. I have added some more requirements. 
Thanking you :)

Comment: Can u please have a look on the syntax. It shows some unexpected token error. Sorry for the trouble again.

Comment: Thank you for the corrected syntax :)

Sorry, one more condition too. Since the phone number 1234 and 5789 are part of email id abc@gmail.com, It need not be included in the output against the empty email value.

Can you please check that too.

Comment: Sorry, again I am getting some error in the Second solution with duplicate suppression as "errmsg" : "exception: the $unwind field path must be specified as a string", "code" : 15981. Don't know why.

Comment: In the first pipeline, I am getting output as 
{
 "_id" : 1234,
 "emails" : [
  {
   "email" : "",
   "_id" : ObjectId("58e880e56774f81f108b4567")
  },
  {
   "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
   "_id" : ObjectId("58e879052b614ce778fb7af2")
  }
 ],
 "countNonBlank" : 1
}
Getting emails as an array. But the error still exists.

In the fourth pipeline, we are using phone: '$_id' in project. What we are supposed to get over there.

Comment: I am using mongo version 2.6.10 (I know it is too old) in my local system and 3.0.1 in my server. That unwind path comand will only recognised in 3.2 above version. :(

Comment: I simply gave it as {$unwind: '$emails'} in the pipeline and it worked. :) One more change I did is that instead of $first in the second last pipeline, I gave $last to get 1234 as phone number against abc@gmail.com.

Thank you Julien TASSIN for your timely support :)